# Call to a member function setCanReadPrice() on boolean During rewrite Adminhtml Block

Tags: adminhtml, overrides

I've tried to rewrite '**Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select**'  and

'**Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option**' Block but i got a error like.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setCanReadPrice() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php on line 193

Here is my config.xml file code with file path:

> /app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Eventprice_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Eventprice_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Model</class>
            </eventprice_meta>

              <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                  <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                        Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
                    </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
                </rewrite>
              </catalog>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <eventprice_sql>
                <setup>
                    <module>Eventprice_Meta</module>
                </setup>
            </eventprice_sql>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <eventprice_meta>
                <class>Eventprice_Meta_Block</class>
            </eventprice_meta>
            <adminhtml> 
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                        Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
                    </catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here is my Select.php file code with path:

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php
class Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('sphere/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml');
        $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
        $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
    }
}
?>
```

This is my Option.php files code with path:

> app/code/local/Eventprice/Meta/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php

```
<?php
class Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('sphere/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml');
        $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
        $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
    }
    public function getOptionValues()
    {
       // I want change the code into this function so for that I want to overwrite this class
    }
}
```

I've followed the http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options tutorials to add new field.

This doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
     Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select
</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
```

to

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_select>
```

You should not have spaces or new line characters inside the xml tags. Magento doesn't trim them.

To the same for

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
    Eventprice_Meta_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
```